# Clojurescript this-as macro points to global object

Tags: clojurescript, reactjs

During writting reactjs tutorial in clojurescrtipt i've found that `this-as` macro compiles to

`(function(){var t = this; return t;}`

which always points to window inside react classes. Sometimes i can workaround this by `js* this` but not inside `let` or `map` cuz they are also compiled to functions.

**How can i access react js `this` inside `let` form?**

Situation on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VkebS/57/

and a piece of tutorial FYI:

```
(def comment-list 
  (React/createClass 
   #js{:render 
       (fn [] (dom/div #js {:className "commentList"}
                       (let [d (this-as t (.. t -props -data))]
                         (map #(commnt #js {:author (:author %)} (:text %)) d))))}))
```

PS: i can use native array for data and native map function

```
(def comment-list 
  (React/createClass 
   #js{:render 
       (fn [] (dom/div #js {:className "commentList"}
                       (.map (.. (js* "this") -props -data) #(commnt #js {:author (:author %)} (:text %)))))}))
```

that works, but...

Comment: give more info please: versions of clojurescript, om (project.clj). Provide full (non)working example in cljs.

Comment: btw this-as compiles correct for me: `var d = (function (){var t = this;return t.props.data;
})()`

Comment: If you solve the issue feel free to add an answer and accept.

Comment: Cljs build 2120. Full example is based on luminus and uses [om](https://github.com/swannodette/om) lib, from wich i take tags macros. I've "solve" the problem by using native map function as i mentioned in PS. My goal was just checking current usability of React-Clojurescript union for production development even if i can use it in non-100%-clojure-way. I've done the tut, but have some troubles with advanced mode for now. If someone is interested i can create repo with tutorial.

Comment: @edbond, btw event if this-as compiles as in your example we have situation when this is unbound. I made fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VkebS/58/

Comment: yes, it will be interesting to see the repo. It could be added to om wiki in future.

Comment: Here you are: https://github.com/amakurin/reactjs-tutorial-cljs I'm not shure if it will be interesting for om users - i use only tag macros. todomvc is ofcourse much much more interesting and desirable.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but could someone tell me what `js*` does?  Or rather, where I can find documentation about it?  It's impossible to search for effectively, even with symhound, and it's not in the Clojurescript cheatsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this-as` works if you use it at start of `render` function:

```
(def commnt
  (React/createClass
   #js {:render
        (fn []
          (this-as this
                   (dom/div #js {:className "comment"}
                            (dom/h2 #js {:className "commentAuthor"}
                                    (.. this -props -author))
                            (dom/span #js {:dangerouslySetInnerHTML
                                           #js{:__html
                                               (.makeHtml converter (..  (js* "this") -props -children toString))}}))))}))
```

see also: https://github.com/swannodette/om/blob/master/src/om/dom.cljs#L34